# How to build a dynamic user-page from LDAP (Active Directory) and show this page after logged in?

Tags: authentication-authorization

I have Open Atrium 2 with Drupal 7. User are able to login over the active directory using the [Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP)](https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap) module, which works pretty well.

After login the user should come to its own personal page. In which the user can see his/her personal data and so on. But how to create a dynamic page like a template for this personal page?

I couldn't find any similar on the net. Any help I would appreciate.

**Edit**:

My first step is: After Login over LDAP (active directory) getting all personal data and lead every person to his own page with all this personal data in it.

Can I do this with some appropriate modules or do I have to script this in php or a mix of both (scripting and modules)? And which modules or plugins for Drupal with Open Atrium 2 can help me to get this?

Answer (score 1):

> After login the user should come to it's own personal page.

Whatever page you want to send the user too (different from the default user profile page) can be achieved by using the [Login Destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination) module:

> The Login Destination module allows you to customize the destination
>   that a user is redirected to after logging in, registering to the site
>   (7.x), using a one-time login link or logging out (7.x). The
>   destination can be an internal page or an external URL. It is possible
>   to specify certain conditions like referring pages or user roles and
>   make the destination depend upon them. You may use PHP snippets to
>   provide custom conditions and destinations. It is also possible to
>   keep users on the currently visited page after logging in or out.

Then you said:

> In which he can see his personal data and so on. But how to create a
>   dynamic page like a template for this personal page??

You didn't mention if this page should be the user's profile or a different page simply showing all the account details from LDAP (and possibly other pieces of content). You can embed the user profile on any path you want, see similar question(s) and example solutions at:

[How to show custom user profile fields in a view?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/how-to-show-custom-user-profile-fields-in-a-view)

Or, you can create a View that uses an LDAP Query and simply show information from LDAP on a custom view page, which the ldap module supports. [See the LDAP Query documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1302080).

Comment: Thanks a lot tenken... I think i'll coming in...

The page the user should come in is his personal page with his own data getting from active directory and some new from his group.

I didn't find any good tutorial in which all this good documented :-(